# Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex

Tags: compiling, syntax

I checked several questions at this community about the issue but did not works out as a solution.

I am trying to run the LaTex code on my machine, but it stopped working for this file.

I have tried to reopen an old file that I have implemented before at my machine and it works fine without any error. Can anyone give a hint what shall I do to make it compilable?

[image]

[image]

Error screenshoted below.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your complete code and not the first screenshot, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano the code can not be relevant to this error:-)

Comment: You have just shown an image of some tex document but the error is from windows saying it can't start pdflatex, so since pdflatex didn't even start the contents of the file are not relevant.  the usual reason for pdflatex not starting is that it is not installed or the editor configuration is wrong and the editor is looking in the wrong place for the executable, hard to guess from the information you have given.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I often do not understand the question in English and I asked the entire code to understand the problem. Thanksssssssss David.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle now the configuration is screenshotted also. Can you check them please?

Comment: I don't use that editor but you are assuming pdflatex is in the path so if you just open a command box and type `pdflatex` does it start or does windows say unknown command?

Comment: Please use the Window command line  and type `pdflatex --version`.  Then we can see whether all links are correct.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel i tried the command but did not work, so I screenshotted the 'about' tab

Comment: @Krebto: That means. It's not an issue with your editor. It mean you haven't installed LaTeX. Did you install TeXLive or MikTeX?

Comment: No I did not, but I am wondering why shall I install them since my usage for this software in writing my previous research papers was ok without using them.

Comment: The editor is jut that and editor to write some text to disk. An external programme is needed to convert that text (code) into a PDF file. Since users taste in editor varies a lot, editor and conversion programme has to be installed separately. So you need to install either MikTeX or TeXLive to have access to the pdflatex programme. Alternatively, if you do not want to do that, you can just use an online system like sharelatex, where LaTeX editor and previewer runs in your browser.

Comment: @daleif thank you for the hint. I will download and try them and see If its works. You can post your comment as an answer so that I can upvote it and accept it.

Comment: I don't think it is worth it, if your things work after installing LaTeX, just delete your question. We have seen this issue many times, so it will not really help the archives.